# Text sloped along regular polygon side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have text sloped along the sides of a `regular polygon` triangle, but `sloped` doesn't do the trick. I guess that's because the node is at a point, not on a path. How can I get `side 1` sloped?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[buffer] (triangle) {} ;
    \node[sloped,font=\footnotesize] at (triangle.side 1) {Side 1}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: For a [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) alternative, see p 71 of the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).

Comment: A quick fix is to use the options `[rotate=60,above]` instead of `[sloped]`

Comment: @KevinC Yes, that's a quick, dirty and non-dynamic fix ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `[sloped]` option causes the node text to be sloped with respect to a path. But a path is absent in your second `\node` command.

A solution to this is to add a path that draws an invisible line along a side, and rotate the node to have the same slope as that line. The following macro does the trick:

```
\newcommand\mytext[3][above]{\path(s.corner #2)--(s.side #2) node[sloped,at end,#1]{#3};}
```

It takes 3 arguments:

1. The first argument is optional, has a default value `[above]` which puts the text above the chosen side
2. The second argument specifies which side you want to put text at
3. The third argument allows input of the content.

### Example with triangle

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}

\newcommand\mytext[3][above]{\path(s.corner #2)--(s.side #2) node[sloped,at end,#1]{#3};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[buffer] (s) {} ;
    % \node[sloped,font=\footnotesize] at (triangle.side 1) {Side 1}; 
    \mytext{1}{side 1}
    \mytext[below,green]{2}{side 2}
    \mytext[above,red]{3}{side 3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Example with hexagon

```
\mytext{1}{\footnotesize side 1}
\mytext[below,green]{5}{\footnotesize side 5}
\mytext[below,red]{3}{\footnotesize side 3}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\N{10}
\def\Offset{ 45 }
\psset{nrot=:D}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1]{0}{360}{3.7 t \Offset add PtoC}{X}
\multido{\ia=0+1,\ib=1+1}{\N}{\ncline{X\ia}{X\ib}\nbput{$(\ia,\ib)$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Miscellaneous

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\def\Offset{ 45 }
\psset{nrot=:D}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=3+1}{10}{%
\def\N{\i}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1]{0}{360}{3.7 t \Offset add PtoC}{X}
\multido{\ia=0+1,\ib=1+1}{\N}{\ncline{X\ia}{X\ib}\nbput{$(\ia,\ib)$}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But I must admit I'm looking for the TikZ solution. Maybe I'll look into PSTricks some day :-)

Comment: @Holene: No problem.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps somebody else knows a way to make `regular polygon` behave as intended, but if not you could just use some plain TikZ, and place the labels by hand. :-)

Here's one way to do it, with some `scope`'s and a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw, regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [buffer] (triangle) {} ;
    
    \newcommand*{\rot}[1]{#1 * 120 - 60} % note 1
    
    \foreach \s/\label in {1/tea, 2/coffee, 3/juice} { % note 2
        \begin{scope}[rotate=\rot{\s}, yshift=1.7em]   % note 3
            \node [rotate=\rot{\s}] {\label};
        \end{scope}
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

Notes:

1. This is a function that works our how far around you rotate the label for side 1 to match side 1, side 2, etc.

   I'd pretend to be able to remember how TikZ does angles, but this mostly just arose from trial and error. It's fairly simple though, so it can be easily extended for larger polygons.
2. Swap out the items in this list to relabel the sides. If you don't want anything on side n, then leave out the `n/$something` pair. Again, this can be extended for larger polygons if you want.
3. The `yshift` sets how far the labels are spaced from the polygon. I got this by trial and error, and picking what I thought looked "nice".